# How can I disable certain options in select option drop down based on time and day?

Tags: php

I want certain options from this drop down menu to be locked based on the time and day, based off the NFL schedule. Not sure how I would go about isolating each option and disabling them. An example or advice would help give me an idea of where to go next with this. Thanks!

```
<form action="login_success.php" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend>Pick</legend>
<select id="tm1" name="teams">
<option value="wr">Washington Redskins</option>
<option value="nyg">New York Giants</option>
<option value="pe">Philadelphia Eagles</option>
<option value="dc">Dallas Cowboys</option>
<option value="br">Baltimore Ravens</option>
<option value="ps">Pittsburgh Steelers</option>
<option value="tt">Tennessee Titans</option>
<option value="gbp">Green Bay Packers</option>
<option value="ss">Seattle Seahawks</option>
<option value="cbr">Cleveland Browns</option>
<option value="bb">Buffalo Bills</option>
<option value="jj">Jacksonville Jaguars</option>
<option value="ic">Indianapolis Colts</option>
<option value="ht">Houston Texans</option>
<option value="kcc">Kansas City Chiefs</option>
<option value="md">Miami Dolphins</option>
<option value="nep">New England Patriots</option>
<option value="nyj">New York Jets</option>
<option value="slr">Saint Louis Rams</option>
<option value="nos">New Orleans Saints</option>
<option value="mv">Minnesota Vikings</option>
<option value="tbb">Tampa Bay Buccaneers</option>
<option value="ac">Arizona Cardinals</option>
<option value="af">Atlanta Falcons</option>
<option value="sf49">San Francisco 49ers</option>
<option value="sdc">San Diego Chargers</option>
<option value="or">Oakland Raiders</option>
<option value="db">Denver Broncos</option>
<option value="cbe">Cincinnati Bengals</option>
<option value="cp">Carolina Panthers</option>
<option value="dl">Detroit Lions</option>
<option value="cbea">Chicago Bears</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the time of day using the `date()` function.  Below is an example of hours (24 hour format) and minutes using UTC.

```
$time = date('G:i');

echo $time;
```

Here's a listing of all the modifiers: [PHP date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Then you can just do a conditional `if{}` to render the HTML you need to disable a specific option field if the values are between a certain time and then render the option field to include `disabled` or not like so:

```
<option value="value1" disabled>value1</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabled option:

```
<option value="ac">Arizona Cardinals</option>
```

Disabled option:

```
<option value="ac" disabled>Arizona Cardinals</option>
```

Comment: I realize I can just  disable individual options but I want it done automatically due to the date/time based off of a schedule

Answer (score 0):

This, or a facsimile there of  will accomplish disabling an option based on the hour by military time. You will need to adjust the times of course and can make it more precise depenting on how you make use of `date()`. 
In the example all times are set to disable between noon and 2pm

```
<form action="login_success.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Pick</legend>
        <select id="tm1" name="teams">
        <?php
        $tt = date("H");
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="wr"'.$dis.'>Washington Redskins</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="nyg"'.$dis.'>New York Giants</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="pe"'.$dis.'>Philadelphia Eagles</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="dc"'.$dis.'>Dallas Cowboys</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="br"'.$dis.'>Baltimore Ravens</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="ps"'.$dis.'>Pittsburgh Steelers</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="tt"'.$dis.'>Tennessee Titans</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="gbp"'.$dis.'>Green Bay Packers</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="ss"'.$dis.'>Seattle Seahawks</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="cbr"'.$dis.'>Cleveland Browns</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="bb"'.$dis.'>Buffalo Bills</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="jj"'.$dis.'>Jacksonville Jaguars</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="ic"'.$dis.'>Indianapolis Colts</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="ht"'.$dis.'>Houston Texans</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="kcc"'.$dis.'>Kansas City Chiefs</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="md"'.$dis.'>Miami Dolphins</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="nep"'.$dis.'>New England Patriots</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="nyj"'.$dis.'>New York Jets</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="slr"'.$dis.'>Saint Louis Rams</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="nos"'.$dis.'>New Orleans Saints</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="mv"'.$dis.'>Minnesota Vikings</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="tbb"'.$dis.'>Tampa Bay Buccaneers</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="ac"'.$dis.'>Arizona Cardinals</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="af"'.$dis.'>Atlanta Falcons</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="sf49"'.$dis.'>San Francisco 49ers</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="sdc"'.$dis.'>San Diego Chargers</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="or"'.$dis.'>Oakland Raiders</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="db"'.$dis.'>Denver Broncos</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="cbe"'.$dis.'>Cincinnati Bengals</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="cp"'.$dis.'>Carolina Panthers</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="dl"'.$dis.'>Detroit Lions</option>';
        if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="cbea"'.$dis.'>Chicago Bears</option>';
        ?>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```